# Django, send email with unsubscribe using Mailchimp list

Tags: django, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill to send emails and using Mailchimp for the users list.

I want to add an unsubscribe link in each email, so I put this code in my html template:

```
<a href="http://myappname.us8.list-manage.com/unsubscribe?u=<number>&id=<id_list>">
    Click here.
</a>
```

When I send this link through Mandrill I can't access directly. Any idea? or if there is a better solution to this? If I put this link in my browser it work.

Answer (score 1):

Mandrill / Mailchimp should be able to handle automatically merging in the unsubscribe link for you. Their built-in tools for adding a link like this are fairly robust and handle generating unique urls for each recipient.